# How to create UTF8 text file in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, utf-8

I am using fileout.write method for writing text file in MS Acess vba but text file is not displaying some characters,now i want to generate text file having utf8 functionality using same methoed so that after every loop row will be added in same file.My code is given below.Below mentioned code is generating and updating same text file but file don't have utf8 functionality.

```
Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\Data\skouts" & Format(Now(), "_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm") & ".txt", True, True)
mydata = html.getElementById("shop-information").innerText
Fileout.write mydata
```

Following method is displaying proper characters but it is updating first url value into other i.e in text file only last url value is visible i.e it is not adding value in text file it is just updating only one value.

```
Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
mydata = html.getElementById("shop-information").innerText
fsT.WriteText mydata
fsT.SaveToFile sFileName, 2 'Save binary data To disk
```

Resulting text file is given below
EπικοινωνίαWebsite: [www.abox.gr](http://www.abox.gr) Τηλέφωνο: 2103003192 ΚαταστήαταΣηείο παραλαής - Δεν έχει ιτρίνα Σοφοκλή Βενιζέλου 58, Τ.Κ. 12131, Περιστέρι, Αττική - 2103003192 Κατάστηα Παπαδιαάντη 1, Τ.Κ. 14562, Κηφισιά, Αττική Τρόποι πληρωήςΠιστωτική κάρταΤραπεζική κατάθεση Αντικαταολή Αριθός Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.150459301000

Comment: UTF-8 [is not](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) Unicode, it is one of the possible Unicode encodings. `CreateTextFile` with the third argument set to `True` creates a Unicode file. If you are not seeing characters correctly in that file, then either `mydata` is already corrupted and does not contain them, or the tool with which you are viewing the resulting file is not able to display it correctly.

Comment: Is the webpage in UTF-8? If you open the resulting fso.CreateTextFile, what is the encoding? (If you cannot determine that, download Notepad++, in the bottom right it tells you the encoding.

Comment: @StureS `innerText` returns a `String`, which means it's a UTF-16 Unicode, regardless of what the declared webpage encoding was for the purpose of network transfer.

Comment: actully output is in greek language and above method is not displaying characters properly.e.g just like following characters.2 Καταστήματα< please check store information on following url.https://www.skroutz.gr/m/6013/Abox#shop-presentation

Comment: I still like to know what the resulting text file encoding is.

Comment: UTF-8 BOM encoding is visible in textpad

Comment: Can you supply the resulting text file?

Comment: kindly guide how to upload text file

Comment: Please check now i upload output text

Comment: So your file is correct in both cases, but the tool with which you are trying to view it is only able to display UTF-8 that ADODB produces, not UTF-16 that FSO produces.

Comment: Your link leads to an ad, not your text file. Please use pastebin.com or codeshare.io to publish the text file

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use addodb.stream, but it seems to be a matter of how to apply this. Once you read the contents of the file, you will just need to rewrite it by  the new characters.

```
With fsT
    .Type = 2
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile sFilename
    mydata = HTML.getElementById("shop-information").innerText
    .WriteText vbCrLf & mydata
    .SaveToFile sFilename, 2
End With
```